# Find a sheet based on a cell name, then find the entry based on a different cell name, and fill in the values from adjacent cells

Tags: vba

I'm pretty new to VBA, I've got a spread sheet that has a list of vehicle ID's in a row of columns, and different identifiers (ID) in column A.

So far I'm able to search for the sheet with the vehicle name and copy a range of cells to the main sheet. I'm trying to make it so that once it finds the specific vehicle sheet, it looks for the specific ID and pulls that in, rather than copy a set range of cells. I'm having it return nothing now, and when I had it before excel would crash, so I assumed I was in some sort of endless loop.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range, c As Range
Dim ECU_Ovv As Range, ECU_V As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Overview") 'main worksheet to copy everything to
Set Rng = ws.Cells(3, 3).Resize(3, LastColumn) ' I;ve calculated LastColumn earlier, it's defined as a Long

Set ECU_Ovv = ws.Cells(5, 2).Resize(LastRow, 2)

For Each sh In Sheets
    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        If sh.Name = c Then
            'Find row range for specific vehicle
            LastRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            Set ECU_V = sh.Cells(5, 2).Resize(LastRow, 2) ' this is the only syntax I could figure out to get it to let me set a range with a calculated variable 
            
            For Each ECU_Ovv In ECU_V.Cells 'now look for the ID in the specific sheet
                If ECU_Ovv.Cells = ECU_V.Cells Then
                    a = ECU_Ovv.Value 'Put this here to see if I am able to match ID's from the main sheet to the specific sheet
                'sh.Range("D12:D47").Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(24, c.Column) 'this was working but it's hardcoded so any change in the sheets would break it
                    
                End If
               
             Next ECU_Ovv
               
        End If
    Next c
Next sh
```

I'm planning on adding a copy cell, 2 columns over (from the found ID) to the column of the vehicle (Rng), but I'll cross that bridge when I get there!

Comment: Try researching `INDEX/MATCH`, or depending on your Excel version you could also use `XLOOKUP`, or if you want to go old school you could use `VLOOKUP`. I have listed these in order of preference, for various technical reasons.

Comment: Post a screen shot of what you have, or better yet, share a simplified copy. Google sheets is pretty conducive to that.

Comment: @ed2, thank you. I'm looking into Index/Match, it seems like it could solve my issue and simplify my code with only 1 nested for loop. Working on implementing it, getting some errors but making progress! Thank you